# Getting "com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The responseTo in the response does not match the requestId in the request" while connecting to mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My app is using Spring-Boot framework. Everything was working fine until GC overhead error occurred. GC error was recovered but mongodb connection was giving this error continuously after it. But at the same time, other applications which were using same mongodb server was able to connect to it normally. As soon as I restarted my spring-boot app, this error was gone.

Exception was `com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The responseTo (130) in the response does not match the requestId (131) in the request.` for every request, responseTo and requestId values were different.

I want to know if this issue was because of OutOfMemoryError? If not, what are the other possible reasons for this error?

Comment: That error should have nothing to do with the GC error. Your error is most likely because of the incompatibility between Java mongo driver version and your mongodb server version.